# How can I get heart rate data (continuous measurement) from MiBand 2 in my own app?

Tags: android, google-fit, heartbeat, xiaomi

I'm developing an android application that needs to get the user's heart rate instantly for analysis. I have a Xiaomi MiBand 2 and would like to use it as data source.

I found several codes in GitHub for applications that connect and get data from the bracelet, but none actually worked. I also tried to do this using Google Fit Api to get heartbeat data provided by the Mi Heart Rate synchronized with Google Fit, but it was not possible to get them either (the HR data is not found).

So if anyone can help me, I'll be grateful.

Comment: can you check with https://developers.google.com/fit/android/samples

Comment: Have you tried visiting this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311874/heart-rate-measuring-using-xiaomi-miband-and-ble)?